# Звёздочки в терминале linux mint при вводе пароля

Tags: консоль, linux-mint

В Linux Mint 19 по умолчанию включено отображение звуздочек при вводе пароля в терминале. Хочу выключить. Смотрел /etc/sudoers, там все как и должно быть, там звездочки не отключить. Смотрел .bashrc, там тоже не нашел. Может кто знает как отключить звездочки. Не спрашивайте чем они мне помешали. Просто нужно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это настраивается с помощью значения pwfeedback в /etc/sudoers, а именно в строке:

```
Defaults env_reset,pwfeedback
```

Вот его нужно убрать оттуда (вместе с запятой конечно же), а если его там нет, то стоит просмотреть в файлах, расположенных в /etc/sudoers.d/

Comment: Да. в /etc/sudoers.d/0pwfeedback закомментировал содержимое. Все получилось. Спасибо!